# How to get the handler of an opened powerpoint presentation in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to get the handler of a powerpoint presentation. Typically, I use the following instruction:

```
Set pres = PowerPoint.application.Presentations(pptFile)
```

I get the following error message:

> 'an activex component can't create object'
>
> pptFile is supposed to be already open

Any Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to open the same presentation twice, something like this:

```
Dim pptFile As String
pptFile = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Desktop\ppp.pptx"

Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

Dim pres As Presentation

For Each pres in pptApp.Presentations
   If pres.FullName = pptFile then
      ' found it!
      Exit For
   End If
End If

' And possibly do this to open the file if it's not already open
If pres Is Nothing Then
   Set pres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(pptFile)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also try this command:

```
Set pres = GetObject(pptFile)
```

Automation will open the file if it isn't open, and it won't open the file again if it is already open.